# How do I store key-strokes?

Tags: c++, winapi, gdi

I have an empty win32 project.

```
CASE WM_CHAR:
```

under this case  I need to store each keystroke in an array, then output it to the screen using

```
TextOut();
```

I figured it's going to be something like this:

```
char store[LARGE_NUMBER];
```

then under the case wm_char header I store the character in store then use a counter to move along the array for each key which is pressed. I just don't know how to record a specific key on the keyboard, not just any key - which calls the wm_char case.

Thanks

Comment: First of all, use `std::vector`. It can dynamically resize itself as it needs to, and has a `size()` function to tell you where it's at. If you use, say, a `std::vector<char>`, you can pass `vec.data()` to `TextOut` to print it. I don't understand what you mean with your question, though. Firstly, it calls the appropriate `WM_KEY*` messages. By using `TranslateMessage`, a `WM_CHAR` message is generated as well. You can filter based on the value you're putting in your buffer, can you not?

Comment: I just need to store each key press in an array of chars, by key press I mean the character, not the unicode. I just put WM_CHAR there because I figured the program responds when I press a key on the keyboard(atleast it did when I put a messagebox there)

Comment: Well, `chars.push_back(wParam);` should do just that when using a vector and `WM_CHAR`. Make sure you use `TranslateMessage` in your message pump.

Answer (score 1):

The `wParam` parameter holds the character code of the key that was pressed. Take a look at [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646276%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). `lParam` holds further information about the key press (was it a special key, was the key held down etc.).

Comment: I think key code is a bit misleading. I've always used `WM_KEY*` myself, but the documentation says character code, meaning `VK_NUM6` would be a `'6'` in `wParam`, not the key code, unless I'm misunderstanding the documentation.